# How to do a one-time thing in a recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, insert, element

I want to recursively insert an element into an already-sorted array, printing out the desired output on the move. Here's my code so far:

```
static void recursivelyInsertElement(int[] array, int start, int elem) {
    if (start == array.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (array[start] > elem) {
        System.out.print(elem + " ");
    }

    System.out.print(array[start] + " ");
    recursivelyInsertElement(array, start + 1, elem);
}
```

The issue here is that once it finds where to put the element I'd like to insert, it doesn't stop doing so until the end of the function. How can I make it add it just once?

What I managed to think of is to add an additional `boolean` function argument which is `false` by default. Then make the second `if` like this:

```
if (array[start] > elem && !isAdded) {
    System.out.print(elem + " ");
    isAdded = true;
}
```

This surprisingly works but is super ugly. Isn't there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
static void recursivelyInsertElement(int[] array, int start, int elem) {
    if (start == array.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (array[start] > elem) {
        System.out.print(elem + " ");
        printArrayAfterIndex(array,start);
    }

    System.out.print(array[start] + " ");
    recursivelyInsertElement(array, start + 1, elem);
}
```

And write a simple function afterwards.

Comment: My array is sorted. So the element I'd like to insert won't necesserily go at the end of it.

Comment: Right, i misunderstood you in first place, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Despite it being a little ugly, I think the extra parameter is your best bet.  The recursive function needs to know if it needs to do that "1 time" thing so, in my opinion, your best options are to either pass a bool to the function or keep a global variable (handy but frowned upon in some circles).

I also like @Eyal's solution; I'm just torn between adding a single extra boolean variable vs. creating an entire extra function.

Comment: The "extra" benefit in a print function is that the recursion stops when found the place of the element. So it opens just one more frame in the stack and then rolls back. If you pass a boolean you will keep opening frames until you reach the end. For large arrays you might also need to add size to the stack.

Comment: Yes, I like @Eyal's solution too. And even though I'd probably use it in the end, I noticed that a downside of the `boolean` variable approach is that it doesn't insert the element if it's bigger than all others. Can it somehow be fixed (by still using a boolean, I mean)?

Comment: You definitely want to keep the IF's in that order; your first IF is ensuring that you're staying in the array.  It can still work with a bool but you would have to re-arrange your logic in the IF condition a little.  The more I think about it, especially in terms of the stack as Eyal mentioned, the more I like their solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find at every iteration if the current position is the right place to insert the element:

```
static void recursivelyInsertElement(int[] array, int start, int elem) {
    boolean isBelowCurrent  = start == array.length || elem < array[start];
    boolean isAbovePrevious = start == 0 || elem >= array[start - 1];

    if (isBelowCurrent && isAbovePrevious) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }

    if (start < array.length) {
        System.out.println(array[start]);
        recursivelyInsertElement(array, start + 1, elem);
    } 
}
```